# Evaluating a $1$-form on a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I have a homework question that says  to evaluate the $1$-form $\phi=x^2 dx - y^2 dz$ on the vector field $V= x U_1 + y U_2 + z U_3$.
How do I go about solving this?  I've tried reading the book but I can't make any sense of it.

Comment: What are your $U_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\require{cancel}\{U_1,U_2,U_3\}$ is the natural frame in $\Bbb R^3$, just remember that ${\rm d}x(U_1) = 1$, ${\rm d}x(U_2) = {\rm d}x(U_3) = 0$, and similarly for ${\rm d}z$. Use linearity: $$\phi(V) = x^2{\rm d}x(V) - y^2{\rm d}z(V),$$but for example, $${\rm d}x(V) = x\,\cancelto{1}{{\rm d}x(U_1)} + y\,\cancelto{0}{{\rm d}x(U_2)} + z\,\cancelto{0}{{\rm d}x(U_3)} = x.$$Now you finish it!

Comment: Thank you.  That really helped.

Comment: So then if I have a vector field W= xy (U_1-U_3) + yz (U_1-U_2) and I am supposed to calculate phi(W) I should get x^3*y+x^2*y*z+x*y^3 as the result correct?

Comment: Just write $W = (xy-yz)U_1 - yz U_2 - xyU_3$ and do the computation just like above. You should get $x^2(xy-yz)- y^2(-xy)$.

Comment: How did you get the (xy-yz)*U_1?  Shouldn't it be (xy+yz)U_1?

Comment: I meant $xy+yz$ instead, sorry. The idea was to distribute everything and write it as a combination of the $U_i$ explictily.

Comment: OK.  So I did it right.  Awesome!

Comment: @IvoTerek: Fancy schmancy. You'll have to teach me how to do those cute arrows in MathJax. :)

Comment: @Ted sure! You must add (between dollars) \require{cancel}. Then \cancelto{foo1}{foo2} does the trick!